# Find longest increasing subarray from 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two arrays `A` and `B` of size `n`. From these arrays, build an array `C` such that the values in it are non-decreasing.
Select two index positions `i` and `j` in such a way that the sub arrays `A[i..j] and B[i..j]` can be used to form `C`.
Finally return the size of the array `C` which is `(j-i+1)`

**Example:**

```
A = [2,7,3]
B = [4,2,6]

C = [2,2,3] formed by selecting i=0 and j = 2, that is min(2,4), min(7,2), max(3,6) = [2,2,3] which is non-decreasing.

so result is j-i+1 = 3
```

**Example:**

```
A = [5,2,4,1]
B = [3,6,2,2]

C = [2,2,2] formed by selecting i=1 and j = 3, that is min(2,6), min(4,2), max(1,2) = [2,2,2] which is non-decreasing.

so result is j-i+1 = 3
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
public int solve(int[] A, int[] B) {
int result = 0, s = 0, n = A.length;
int last = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int a = A[i], b = B[i];
    if(last == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        s = 1;
        last =Math.min(a,b); 
    } else {
        int min = Math.min(a,b), max = Math.max(a,b);
        if(last <= min) {
            last = min;
            s++;
        } else {
            if(last <= max) {
                last = max;
                s++;
            } else {
                last = min;
                s = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    result = Math.max(result, s);
}
result = Math.max(result, s);
if(result == 0) result = 1;
return result;
}
```

This works fine for some cases only. Here I am not considering the all possible paths to get the correct result. How to do that in less time complexity.

Comment: You might find this easier to split the operation to find an increasing span from the loop to scan the list. Put the first in a function that returns the first item not in the span. You can concentrate on getting that right fist, then handle the rest knowing one part is done.

Comment: A lot of time a span is easier to handle if you keep track of "first included" and "first excluded" (i.e "end limit"), as in indexes 2, 3, and 4 would be first=2, limit=5. Python does it this way, and lets you denote e.g. 2:2 as having length 0 without adding special cases of extra flags. Also the length is just limit - first, very simple

Comment: In the main loop, you need to keep track of two spans: the previous longest, and the current being checked. If the one being checked turns out to be longer, just replace the old indexes with the new ones. In both cases, continue looking for the next increasing span.

Comment: I think I'd start by putting all of the `min` values into array `A`, and all of the `max` values into array `B`. Then it's easier to reason about the problem, and the code to solve the problem is cleaner. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Qau.png) with smaller values on top, and larger values on the bottom.

Comment: I don't understand this part of the question, _"... build an array `C` such that the values in it or non-decreasing. ..."_.

Comment: Turn it into a DAG with elts as nodes and arcs to valid plausible successors (not trumped by a nearer lesser valid successor). Add a source node with arcs to all nodes w no indegree. Find longest path in O(V + E)

Comment: @Dave If this is an introductory class just introducing arrays, I don't think they'll have covered directed acyclic graphs, though your solution is probably the most straightforward, given there might be multiple candidates starting at the same index (e.g. A=[1,2,3,2] and B=[2, 2, 2, 4] could produce at least four possible C arrays). They're prpbably looking for some sort of repetitive linear search, maybe something recursive would work.

Comment: @Reilas I take that to mean build the array such that the values are in ascending order (for ints. that would be their natural order).  But adjacent values may be equal to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy one.  Imagine the directed graph in which every number in A or B has an edge to each number that could follow it.  This is a directed acyclic graph with max in-degree and max out-degree 2.

Now just find the longest path in that graph.

It's easy to find the longest path in a DAG by processing the vertices in topological order, which is conveniently the same as index order in this problem.

```java
public int solve(int[] A, int[] B) {
  int result = 1;
  int alen = 1, blen = 1, n = A.length;
  if (n<1) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) {
    int a = 1, b = 1;

    if (A[i] >= A[i-1]) {
      a = alen+1;
    }
    if (A[i] >= B[i-1]) {
      a = Math.max(a, blen+1);
    }
    if (B[i] >= A[i-1]) {
      b = alen+1;
    }
    if (B[i] >= B[i-1]) {
      b = Math.max(b, blen+1);
    }
    alen = a;
    blen = b;
    result = Math.max(result,alen);
    result = Math.max(result,blen);
  }
  return result;
}
```